# Slack oauth.access API returns bad_redirect_uri without requesting a redirect_uri

Tags: javascript, oauth, slack, slack-api

Trying to setup oAuth with slack for custom app and slack's API is returning `{"ok":false,"error":"bad_redirect_uri"}`. I'm not setting a redirect for oauth.access, even if I do set one I still get same error.

The app is configured to allow localhost and public domain.

This is the request I am doing

```
const res = await request({
  method: 'post',
  uri: 'https://slack.com/api/oauth.access',
  auth: {
    user: process.env.SLACK_CLIENT_ID,
    pass: process.env.SLACK_CLIENT_SECRET,
  },
  form: {
    code,
    // redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:3100',
  },
});
```

To kick off auth flow I am calling this URL from browser:

`https://slack.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=XXX&scope=commands,im:read,im:write&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3100/integrations/slack.request&state=ID`

Answer (score 2):

You can not use `localhost` as redirect_uri.

If you want to use OAuth with your local PC, I would suggest installing a VPN tunnel like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/), that allows you to expose your local PC to the Internet in a relatively safe way. ngrok is also mentioned in one of the [official Slack tutorials](https://api.slack.com/tutorials/tunneling-with-ngrok) as example on how setup a local development environment with Slack.

Also make sure you have a webserver installed on your PC.

Comment: Can I not do this request without a redirect_uri, the slack docs say its optional ? https://api.slack.com/methods/oauth.access

Comment: No. By optional they mean that you do not need to specify that parameter and it will then just take the URL you specified in your Slack app Oauth settings. But the Oauth process always needs the URL to your app so it can reach it after the user logged in

Comment: Ahh okies, will look at ngrok then. Thank you

Comment: What does that uri need to point to? just the root of your app or does it need to return something, the root of my app returns nothing, so not sure what is the point or purpose.

Comment: @user901790 That URI needs to point to the route of your web app that handles the OAuth flow. As described here: https://api.slack.com/docs/oauth